# Make function to see only specific part of DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

At the moment i'm using following code to get path to selected element

```
if (!(el instanceof Element)) return;
        var path = [];
        while (el.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            var selector = el.nodeName.toLowerCase();
            if (el.id) {
                selector += '#' + el.id;
            } else {
                var sib = el, nth = 1;
                while (sib.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && (sib = sib.previousSibling) && nth++);
                selector += ":nth-child("+nth+")";
            }
            path.unshift(selector);
            el = el.parentNode;
        }
        return path.join(" > ");
```

It returns me correct path in context of my full html page. However i want this function to work not on whole page, but in context of small area of my html page. How do i limit this function to work lets say inside some div#id ?

Comment: Just add the condition `&& (!el.id || el.id !== SOMEID)` to your while loop?

Comment: search on internet for `jquery custom events` and bind/trigger the custom events to the elements whenever required

Comment: @FelixKling add your comment as responce, and i accept it. It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However i want this function to work not on whole page, but in context of small area of my html page. How do i limit this function to work lets say inside some div#id ?

It sounds like you just have to stop traversing up the tree once you reached that particular element. Depending on whether you passed an ID or element to your function, you can either do:

```
while (el.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && (!el.id || el.id !== SOME_ID)) {
```

or

```
while (el.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && el !== SOME_ELEMENT) {
```

Comment: is there any simple way to have sometning like `el.tagName != "table"` ?

Comment: Of course, you can compare any property of the element you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, at least not using the DOM API.

The DOM API allows you to traverse the entire DOM, you can go up as far you please. If you have a reference to the `document` you're free to do anything.

A way to limit access is to write a wrapper for the DOM API. This wrapper will have the functionality you need which may include: making new DOM Nodes, deleting DOM Nodes, setting properties on DOM Nodes. But you wont be able to freely walk the DOM Tree (because this breaks the encapsulation you desire).

The details of such a wrapper are quite complex and there are many choices to make. I'm using an in-house developed framework that combines this with the notation of widgets and it's quite nice.